Does Pharo have a messages or warnings log during a session?
When I started a Pharo image I got a warning about a .sources file being missing because I had renamed the .image, .sources and .changes file to one of my preferences.
It showed up for a while then disappeared, but I suspect it is logged somewhere in the system.
What I'm looking for is along the lines of the Messages log in Emacs
Here is some sample content from two files: {{image-folder}}/PharoDebug.log and
Content from the file - {{image-folder}}/PharoDebug.log
THERE_BE_DRAGONS_HERE
Pharo cannot locate the sources file named {{image-folder}}/Pharo10.0-64bit-28169ae.sources.

Please check that the file is named properly and is in the
same directory as this image.
26 June 2024 4:54:50.964965 am

VM: unix - x86_64 - linux-gnu - CoInterpreter VMMaker-tonel.1 uuid: 97a2c5d3-7db4-0d00-9da7-39dc08c6380e Mar 30 2023
StackToRegisterMappingCogit VMMaker-tonel.1 uuid: 97a2c5d3-7db4-0d00-9da7-39dc08c6380e Mar 30 2023
v9.0.22 - Commit: 421845e - Date: 2023-03-30 09:49:26 +0200

Image: Pharo10.0.0 [Build information: Pharo-10.0.0+build.539.sha.28169ae414c78e07602b31545f43061b4fa7a88a (64 Bit)]

StartupUIManager>>inform:
    Receiver: a StartupUIManager
    Arguments and temporary variables: 
        arg1:   'Pharo cannot locate the sources file named {{image-folder}}...etc...
        tmp1:   nil
    Receiver's instance variables: 
        doNotQuitOnRestart:     false
        uiManager:  nil


PharoFilesOpener(Object)>>inform:
    Receiver: a PharoFilesOpener
    Arguments and temporary variables: 
        arg1:   'Pharo cannot locate the sources file named {{image-folder}}...etc...
    Receiver's instance variables: 
        shouldInformAboutReadOnlyChanges:   nil


PharoFilesOpener>>inform:withRef:
    Receiver: a PharoFilesOpener
    Arguments and temporary variables: 
        arg1:   'Pharo cannot locate &fileRef.

Please check that the file is named prope...etc...
        arg2:   'the sources file named {{image-folder}}...etc...
    Receiver's instance variables: 
        shouldInformAboutReadOnlyChanges:   nil


SourceFileArray>>ensureOpen
    Receiver: a SourceFileArray
    Arguments and temporary variables: 
        tmp1:   nil
        tmp2:   nil
    Receiver's instance variables: 
        files:  #(nil nil)
        readOnlyQueue:  SharedQueue with 0 items
        flushChanges:   true


SmalltalkImage>>openSourceFiles
    Receiver: Smalltalk
    Arguments and temporary variables: 
x
    Receiver's instance variables: 
        globals:    a SystemDictionary(lots of globals)
        specialObjectsArray:    an Array(nil false true #Processor->Processor Bitmap Small...etc...
        vm:     a VirtualMachine


SourceFileArray class>>startUp:
    Receiver: SourceFileArray
    Arguments and temporary variables: 
        arg1:   true
    Receiver's instance variables: 
        superclass:     Object
        methodDict:     a MethodDictionary(#changeRecordsFor:->SourceFileArray>>#changeReco...etc...
        format:     65539
        layout:     a FixedLayout
        organization:   a ClassOrganization
        subclasses:     nil
        name:   #SourceFileArray
        classPool:  a Dictionary()
        sharedPools:    an OrderedCollection()
        environment:    a SystemDictionary(lots of globals)
        category:   #'System-Sources-Sources'


ClassSessionHandler>>startup:
    Receiver: a ClassSessionHandler(SourceFileArray)
    Arguments and temporary variables: 
        arg1:   true
    Receiver's instance variables: 
        registeredClassName:    #SourceFileArray

Content from {{image-directory}}/pharo-local/play-cache/{{date-stamp}}.ombu
OmEntry {
    #tags : {
        #timestamp : DateAndTime [ '2024-06-26T10:46:24.746658+01:00' ],
        #self : OmReference [ '1' ]
    },
    #content : 'Smalltalk tools changeList browseRecentLog'
}

OmEntry {
    #tags : {
        #timestamp : DateAndTime [ '2024-06-26T10:49:02.067969+01:00' ],
        #self : OmReference [ '2' ]
    },
    #content : 'Smalltalk tools changeList browseRecentLog.\r\rSmalltalk '
}

OmEntry {
    #tags : {
        #timestamp : DateAndTime [ '2024-06-26T12:09:38.694579+01:00' ],
        #self : OmReference [ '3' ]
    },
    #content : 'Smalltalk tools changeList browseRecentLog.\r\rSmalltalk \r\rIceRepository registry collect: #workingCopy\r\r'
}


It would help to show us the details.

@tukan The question has been updated with more content from the files. I am sure more of Pharo's other subsystems have output similar to this that may be logged to the same files and viewed.

Thanks for the additional info. Are you starting Pharo manually or via PharoLauncher?

@tukan I'm starting via Pharo Launcher, but I prefer to go for the command line eventually.

I think you are searching for TinyLogger. You could add it to your image and log errors in you Pharo application.
There was also Log4s port but that was for onlder Pharo.
I hope that is what you are looking for.
